# Entity Framework 6: Resolving user permissions by roles (IdentityUserRole)

Tags: entity-framework

I have a process in which an entity changes its state, i  want to get the States that  current user is allowed to transfer to, i have the following expression which when evaluated i'm getting an **NotSupportedException** with the message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
var user = db.Users.Single(...); //Successfully Retrieve the user
var states = db.StateTransitions
    .Join( db.RoleStateTransitions
        .Join( user.Roles,
            rst => rst.RoleID,
            ur => ur.RoleId,
            ( rst, ur ) => rst ),
        wst => wst.StateTransitionID,
        rst => rst.StateTransitionID,
        ( wst, rst ) => wst.FinalState ) ;
```

As you can see joining with user.Roles (collection of IdentityUserRole) is the problem. What is wrong with the previous expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `user.Roles` is a local collection of objects. EF has no way of translating local objects into SQL (even though they are mapped objects). But you can make it work by reducing the local collection to primitive types:

```
var userRoleIds = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id)
                    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId))
                    .ToList();

var states = from wst in db.StateTransitions
             join rst in db.RoleStateTransitions
                           .Where(x => userRoleIds.Contains(x.RoleId))
                 on wst.StateTransitionID equals rst.StateTransitionID
             select wst.FinalState;
```

Or maybe even one query:

```
var states = from wst in db.StateTransitions
             join rst in db.RoleStateTransitions
                 on wst.StateTransitionID equals rst.StateTransitionID
             join role in db.Roles
                 on rst.ROleId equals role.RoleId
             where role.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == id)
             select wst.FinalState;
```

(Assuming there is a many to many between `User` and `Role`).

Comment: Gert, i had realized the problem and it is working well right now, anyway i like your second approach. Currently i just have a one-to-many from User to Role but i'm evaluating to configure a many-to-many relationship between them and go that way. Thanks